# Parametrization of right circular cone

Tags: geometry, parametric

community!

> Write the parametric equations of a right circular cone of height $h$
>   and semi-aperture $α$, lying on the plane $z = 0$, contained in the first
>   octant, so that the segment between its vertex and the centre of its
>   base projects orthogonally on $z = 0$ in the line $x = y$, $z = 0$.

I am really stuck in this exercise of Computational Geometry. I have no idea how to start.

Anyone could give me hints in how to begin? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I made a sketch with GeoGebra to show you how the cone looks: hope it helps.

You could start writing the parametric equations for a cone whose axis is the z-axis. Then rotate the cone twice: first about y-axis by $(\pi/2-\alpha)$, then about z-axis by $\pi/4$.

[image]